# Repairing cracked fiberglass pool steps

Tags: repair, water, pool, crack, fiberglass

I have a roughly 6" crack on one of my top fiberglass pool steps that slowly allows the water level to drain below the optimal level for the skimmer.

I've found some years old suggested techniques for repairing it but am curious with the introduction of products like "flex seal" and similar things if there isn't a better, easier, more efficient/effective way of repairing it today. Was hoping someone could offer some insight.

Things I have to consider for this repair:

-- The surface is dimpled and not flat.

-- I'll also be converting the pool to saltwater from chlorine after this repair is in place in case that might effect what products to use.

-- I live in midwest USA, winters can sometimes be severe, however during the winter the water level is far below the step with the crack.

Looking for a long-term and effective solution if anyone has any tips to share they would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't necessarily have to look pretty, just has to work reliably.

Cheers

Comment: Flex Seal would make a water-tight seal, but it is intended only as a temporary fix.  For a permanent fix, go with the "years old" techniques.