# How can I repair a cracked inground pool step?

Tags: repair, pool, fiberglass

[image]The top step into my inground pool is cracked.  I saw [Repairing cracked fiberglass pool steps](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/41920/20103) but it references "years old" technique without a useful link.  If someone can point me to that technique, that'd be great.

However I make the crack water tight, I think it would be helpful to provide some support under the step and have looked at various expanding foams ("Great Stuff" and others).  I found one that says it is good for filling voids but it says it needs to be open to air to cure.  If I squirt it through the crack and let it expand below the step, there will be minimal air exposure.

I can't even find a clear answer on what pool steps are made of.  I've heard reference to "fiberglass" but there doesn't seem to be any fiber ends in the crack.  They sort of feel like PVC but I know that can be deceiving.  One pool repair site said acetone can be used to buff out scratches and scuffs. I tried a little on a small scratch and it did work but that's inconclusive.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: A picture of your pool step would be helpful.

Comment: https://blog.royalswimmingpools.com/how-to-repair-cracks-in-pool-steps seems like a good lead but I am still looking